# General Multi Return Statement Question in C#

Tags: c#, return

How to return the value if I doesn't need hit block2.

Does it make sense or not? I think I shouldn't use multi `return`, but I can't replace it with `break`. there is *No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue*.

```
public EnResult MyFun()
{
    bool bRet = default;

    // block1 . higher priority than block2.
    if (true)
    {
    // if bRet = true_1, not need hit block2. That's why I want to nested my code with multi *return*
        return bRet = true_1;  
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    // block2
    if (true)
    {
        return bRet = true_2;
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    return bRet;
}

public enum EnResult
{
    true_1,
    true_2,
    false_1,
    false_2,
    default,
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using multiple return statements per method is not poor coding style at all.  Limiting yourself to one return statement makes sense in C, where you may need to `goto` some common cleanup code that will free pointers, etc., and then return the value you have stored in a variable.  But in C# this is not necessary.

I write methods with multiple return statements all the time.  I would much rather read a method written with multiple return statements where the logic flow is clear, than read a method written with one return statement and somewhat obfuscated logic.

Comment: +1 Your answer is correct. The important rule is Readability. If the function is easier to read with multiple exit points then have multiple return statements, otherwise not. Also refer to - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleFunctionExitPoint and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292702/any-research-on-maintainability-of-guard-statement-vs-single-function-exit-po

Comment: @Unmesh Kondolikar. split to two URLs then. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a "multi-return":

```
public EnResult MyFun()
{
    // I changed 'default' to 'None' because I wasn't sure if it compiled
    EnResult result = EnResult.None;

    // block1 . higher priority than block2.
    if (true)
    {
        result = EnResult.true_1;
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    // block2
    if (result == EnResult.None)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            result = EnResult.true_2;
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public enum EnResult
{
    None,  
    true_1,
    true_2,
    false_1,
    false_2,

}
```

I would prefer using multiple return statements though (your original code). It's much more clear that way IMO.

Comment: Thanks for restructure my code. I think about the performance. Then I need return as early as possible.