# Is it preferable to use an "else" in Python when it's not necessary?

Tags: python, coding-style

I actually use Python and Flask for my devblog. I know that depending of the language, it is advisable to use a explicit `else` when it is not obligatory, but I don't know how it's work in Python.

By example, I have a a function with a `if` that return something if the statement is true. So, The `else` is not necessary because with or without it, the execution continue normally.

```
def foo(bar):
    if not isinstance(foo, list):
        return "an error"
    else: # not necessary 
        return "something"
```

So, I should use it like this, or like :

```
def foo(bar):
    if not isinstance(foo, list):
        return "an error"

    return "something"
```

Comment: I [almost] always "mirror" the execution paths - the exception is quickly throwing an exception :D (Which is different from returning a value.) This is mostly a styling choice (i.e. *Not Constructive*), but I contend that it makes "the actual paths" more distinguished and can prevent some silly mistakes.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of the language but of coding style. So the answer could be: whatever you find more readable.

Comment: Personally I prefer the first for symmetry or a third way which would be to assign a return value in each branch and then have a single `return retvalue` at the end. One slight advantage of _not_ using an `else` or `elif` besides it being an extra line to type, is when you have more than two, it's easier to delete or add one anywhere you want in the chain. Generally I don't believe there's much difference performance-wise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If-Else-Return or just if-Return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191388/if-else-return-or-just-if-return)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will use `if... return...return` instead of `if...return...else...return` because I am lazy. :D

Answer (score 8):

In the first case, Python will add an explicit `return None` to the end of the function - even though we can see it's not really needed. In the second case it doesn't.

I don't see any advantage to having the `else:` there

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...  if 1>2:
...   return 2
...  return 3
... 
>>> def g():
...  if 1>2:
...   return 2
...  else:
...   return 3
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

  4     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 5):

This has already been discussed here: [If-Else-Return or just if-Return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191388/if-else-return-or-just-if-return)

Essentially, the two forms are equivalent in terms of efficiency because the machine has to make a jump anyway.  So it boils down to coding style and you'll have to decide that on your own (or with your team).

Personally, I prefer with the **else** statement for readability.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I had not seen it even if I had search before to post.

Answer (score 1):

It really makes no difference.  Either way will do the same thing.

I prefer the latter, because it's one less line of code.

Je préfère cette dernière

Comment: The [PEP 8 Style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has examples that lean towards that method as well.

Comment: @sharth However, PEP 8 "example" shows throwing an exception, not returning. In addition, it is not drawn out, and thus I would hate to consider it part of the "canon" in PEP 8.

Comment: I also lean towards the latter and phrase a lot of my conditionals like that to cut back on excess indentation.

Comment: @Kiirani I "fix" that by avoiding functions that are too complex. I have prefer branches (in every language I use, with the occasional exception exception) and I can't recall the last time I was overrun with indentation .. maybe if using 8-space indents .. but *ick!* :D

Comment: @pst Restructuring is not always possible, and I probably have a lower tolerance for indentation levels than you :P (not everyone peruses code in an 80x24 terminal window on a semi regular basis..)

Comment: @Kiirani 3 levels deep (inside a function) is about my "max happy" number.

Answer (score 1):

From [Chromium's](http://www.chromium.org/developers/coding-style) style guide:

Don't use else after return:

```
# Bad
if (foo)
  return 1;
else
   return 2;

# Good
if (foo)
  return 1;
return 2;

return foo ? 1 : 2;
```