# else after continue, break or return

Tags: python, if-statement, return, break, continue

I'm getting to this question again from time to time. Is there a general answer on this?

If there is a single if-else construct and the if section has a `continue`, `break` or `return` in it, should it be followed by an `else` for readability or some reasons?

```
if v == 0:
    continue # / break / return
else: # is this necessary?
    ...
```

Comment: Strongly related: [If-Else-Return or just if-Return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191388/if-else-return-or-just-if-return)

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve with your code. It is all about what happens when conditions are satisfied

Comment: @juankysmith: No, the results would be the same since control leaves the loop/function at that point if the condition is `True`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: the issues are the same; this is more than just strongly related.

Comment: If you have a `return` in the if conditional block, then you have a code block that may never be executed; some IDEs will note this for you.  As a general rule, when in doubt of how something is to be written, consult [The Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (aka PEP20).

Comment: @Martijn, since the other question is more focused on performance than readability, I refrained from closing this one as a duplicate. You're right, though, they're very close.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: there are other posts on the same subject, I am sure. If you wanted to find an even better dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, there is no requirement put the `...` inside an `else` clause. Whether or not you do is largely a matter of personal preference.

When I am thinking about how to structure code like this, there are competing considerations. On the one hand, I like to keep the number of nesting levels to a minimum. On the other, I try to use `break` and `continue` in moderation, since to my eye they make the flow of control somewhat harder to follow.

For these reasons, I would almost never use the form shown in your question. Instead, I would write either

```
if v == 0:
  continue
# ...
```

or

```
if v != 0:
  # ...
```

I would generally prefer the latter to the former. The choice largely depends on how much code there is in the `# ...` block (which, as a rule of thumb, I would try to keep to a minimum).

Answer (score 1):

It may not be necessary, but it's a good idea in my opinion because

- Explicit is better than implicit (The Zen of Python, Tim Peters)
- Readability counts (ibid.)

and the indented blocks make it obvious what you want to happen when the condition is `True` or `False`.

```
if foo:
    do_this()
    break
else:
    do_that()
```

Here, `do_this()` and `do_that()` are "on the same level". In my opinion, that looks nicer than

```
if foo:
    do_this()
    break
do_that()
```

Comment: while the first two points are pro, the last statement seems to encourage to omit  the `else`, is that right?

Comment: @embert: No, because then the "implicit `else` clause" would be at a different level of indentation. I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : I think this depends on the context of the usage where we are using the if-else construct. But however for readability , understandability it is better to use else.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question. OP's not asking about what an `if` statement does, but whether the `else` is necessary/advisable when control leaves the loop/function if the condition is `True`.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, didn't get it right on first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

**one**:
for readability.

**two**:

It can help you debug your application. Assume that you have a block of code where the if statement doesn't need an else block and the else block doesn't make any sense and should never be hit.

You can always put a print statement in there or call the error message code to catch possible bad data operations.

I hope this helps.