# python if and else statements error

Tags: python-3.x

Please help me with if and else statements in python. I like to set b according to value of a.

```
a=5
b=0
def fname():
    #less than 5
    if (a < 5): 
        b=100
    #greater than 5 or less than 10
    elif (a >= 5) and (a <= 10):
        b=200
    #greater than 10 or less than 20
    elif (a >10) and (a <= 20):
        b=300
print (b)
fname()
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `fname` any where ? You don't have any `else` statements anywhere

Comment: yes. I add fname() in the end.

Comment: umm... do you do realize that `a` can never be simultaneously under 6 **and** over 10, right

Comment: These are the conditions: 
#if less than 5 b is 100; 
#greater than or equal 5 and  less than 10 b is 200; 
#greater than or equal 10 and  less than 20 b is 300;

Comment: `print`ing `b` before calling `fname()` is not going to show changes made by `fname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `b` in `fname` is not the same `b` that is in the global/outer scope.

An ugly hack to make that work is to add `global b` inside `fname`.

A better way is to pass in the value for `a` to `fname` and have `fname` return the new value for `b` and assign it:

```
def fname(a_number):
    #less than 5
    if a_number < 5: 
        return 100
    #greater than 5 or less than 10
    elif 5 <= a_number <= 10:
        return 200
    #greater than 10 or less than 20
    elif 10 < a_number <= 20:
        return 300        

b = fname(a)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/208880) for more information about scoping and Python.

Comment: Could also make the conditions more readable using comparison chaining: `elif 5 <= a_number <= 10:`

Comment: @EthanFurman: You could also change all elif's to simple if's, because each return ends the function.

Comment: @VPfB:  True, but if just scanning the code the `elif`s make it clear that only one branch will be executed.

Comment: how do i test the value of b?

Comment: @EthanFurman: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191388/if-else-return-or-just-if-return We have just different personal preferences.

Comment: if define  a=5 and print (name)  the result is <function fname at 0x1003c2bf8>.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 5
b = 0


def fname():
    # less than 5
    if (a < 5):
        b = 100
        print(b)
    # greater than 5 or less than 10
    elif (a >= 5) and (a <= 10):
        b = 200
        print(b)
    # greater than 10 or less than 20
    elif (a > 10) and (a <= 20):
        b = 300
        print(b)


fname()
```

if u want to learn about if and else go to - https://youtu.be/no8c4KMYBdU