# Should I write else in case when return inside if

Tags: python

Please consider two approaches:

```
def test(a):
    if a == True:
        return
    else:
        print('no')

def test(a):
    if a == True:
        return
    print('no')
```

What is better way in python? I've heard that explicit is better then implicit, so should I use first one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code style questions should be on programmers.stackexchange.com (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127128/what-is-the-best-style-for-functions-with-multiple-returns-and-if-else-statement)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9191388/270986

Answer (score 4):

The pythonic way is to write it without the extra `else`.

Nice [lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=JVVMMULwR4s) about it (go to minute 5:00).

Answer (score 0):

These look absolutely the same to the interpreter. (You can use [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#dis.dis) to look into the bytecode of the functions).

So use the shorter one.