# What is the real benefit of obeying R1705 in pylint? Is the code really safer?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

With pylint, I know that R1705 warning gets triggered when you put a 'return' inside an 'else'.

This is the warning:
`R1705: Unnecessary "else" after "return" (no-else-return)`

This is what the docs says about it:

`Unnecessary “else” after “return” Used in order to highlight an unnecessary block of code following an if containing a return statement. As such, it will warn when it encounters an else following a chain of ifs, all of them containing a return statement.`

A snippet of code that will trigger R1705:

```
if CONDITION1:
   return something1
else:
   return something2
```

The desired fix to shut down the warning:

```
if CONDITION1:
   return something1
return something2
```

Is it really needed to obey this? What's the benefit? I mean I understand that after returning something from a function there is no way to come back and read further code.

But I find it way more organized to use 'else'.

Comment: The `else` is just redundant because it's already obvious where control will go if the condition isn't met. It also saves a level of indentation in the `else` clause. Of course, you may not want to write code like this because you "find it way more organized to use `else`". It's really up to you, to my mind.

Comment: Thank you ForceBru! I was afraid of something 'punishable' :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're trying to conform to [Mozilla Coding Style](https://web.archive.org/web/20140713115202/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style#General_C.2FC.2B.2B_Practices)
or similar
then R1705 makes sense.
Quoting:

> Don't put an else right after a return (or a break). Delete the else, it's unnecessary and increases indentation level.

Otherwise, you might prefer to disable that warning.
Better still, consider switching to [`flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/),
which tends to stay pretty silent if you've been writing sensible code.

Outside of the Mozilla community,
most folks would rather see simple parallel functional clauses
handled with an `else`, like this:

```
def max(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

Answer (score 5):

This [post](https://dmerej.info/blog/post/else-after-return-yea-or-nay/) gives two different cases for this design decision:

1. Guard clauses.

   ```
   def try_something()
       if precondition():
            result = compute_something()
            return result
       else:
            display_error()
            return None
   ```

The author argues that for several such conditions their inversion and `implicit else` is better:

```
    # Implicit else, inverted condition
    def try_something():

        if not precondition_one():
            display_error_one()
            return

        if not precondition_two():
            display_error_two()
            return

        result = compute_something()
        return result
```

2. Symmetrical clause.

   ```
   # Explicit else
   def check_link(link) -> bool:
       if is_internal_link(link):
           return check_internal_link(link)
       else:
           return check_external_link(link)
   ```

I agree with the author that here explicit is better.

I would also cite a comment from that post, which says that this choice is a choice of paradigm:

> 1. "Explicit else": "if-then-else" is treated as lazy computation and more suited in "functional-first" environments. If this "if-then-else" is applied to large datasets and code in F#, Scala, Haskel, Closure or even SQL - explicitness is preferred. Most probably language/platform itself will encourage to write "pure" code and discourage/make near impossible to make imperative stunts.
> 2. "Implicit else/(explicit return)": computation depends on 100% on side-effects and result is combination of side-effects too. It's impossible to guarantee correctness in strict sense anyway, so explicit return becomes clear declaration: "Because of laws of physics in our Universe, this computation could work incorrect. In majority of such cases this default value will be returned".