# why does pylint complain about Unnecessary "elif" after "return" (no-else-return)?

Tags: python, pylint

why does pylint complain about this code block?

`R1705: Unnecessary "elif" after "return" (no-else-return)`

```py
def f(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    elif a == 2:
        return 2
    return 3
```

To prevent the error, I had to create a temporary variable, which feels less pleasant.

```py
def f(a):
    if a == 1:
        b = 1
    elif a == 2:
        b = 2
    else:
        b = 3

    return b
```

**Solution**:

```py
def f(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    if a == 2:
        return 2
    return 3
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The purpose of an `else` block is to define code that will *not* be executed if the condition is true, so execution wouldn't continue on to the next block.

However, in your code, the main conditional block has a return statement, meaning execution will leave the function, so there's no need for an else block: all subsequent code after the return will, by definition, not be executed if the condition is true. It's redundant. It can be replaced with a simple `if`.

Comment: `elif` is a contraction of "else if".

Comment: but the code perfectly fine, and it makes sense, right? is this a limitation/bug of pylint?

Comment: The code contains a redundant else statement, and pylint notifies you of it, which is precisely its job.

Comment: I see. What's the recommended way of coding such logic?

Comment: Simply replace elif with if - they're semantically identical in this situation without the redundant implicit else.

Answer (score 4):

### pylint is not always correct or helpful

pylint loves to deliver technically correct but unhelpful messages.

```
def f(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    elif a == 2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

might be more readable than

```
def f(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    if a == 2:
        return 2
    return 3
```

for many users, simply because it looks like a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement).

### match-case in Python 3.10

["Structural Pattern Matching"](https://Structural%20Pattern%20Matching) has been added to Python 3.10. Its syntax is powerful and versatile. Among others, it allows simple examples which look like a switch statement:

```
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755912/
why-does-pylint-complain-about-unnecessary-elif-after-return-no-else-return
"""

def match_case_example(value):
    """
    Simple match-case example, for python 3.10+
    see https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/
    """
    match value:
        case 1:
            return 1
        case 2:
            return 2
        case _other:
            return 3


print(match_case_example(4))
# 3
```

Pylint doesn't have *anything* to complain about this script, provided you have Python 3.10 or newer.