# Pylint not understanding an if/else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have the following example function:

```
def example(inp):
    if not isinstance(inp, list):
        return 'Not list'
    else:
        return 'List'

>>> example('asdf')
'Not list'
>>> example(['asdf',])
'List'
```

And yet `pylint` complains that:

> no-else-return: Unnecessary "else" after "return"

Why does it raise that warning, which seems so silly?

Comment: probably because if it returns the value it will not continue evaluationg the else or sth?

Comment: eh, quite dumb ngl. If you're looking for a work around I'd try having the ```else: return``` outside of the if statement.

Comment: Because there's no point putting the code in an else block if the if returns - look at rule pages like https://pheanex.github.io/pylint/ that show passing and failing examples.

Comment: It does understand the `if`/`else` quite well. You can disable the warning if you don't like it.

Comment: Pylint sometimes has dumb opinions. Just silence it.

Comment: LOL "<Here we will explain to the user why this is better and provide some context>" says it all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is equivalent to this shorter code:

```
if not isinstance(inp, list):
    return 'Not list'
return 'List'
```

Specifically, when the body of an `if` ends with a `return`, it doesn't matter whether the code for the false condition is in an `else` or not: it will only be executed if the `if` condition is false, because if the condition is true, the function will return at the end of the `if` body.

Pylint seems to prefer the more compact version. But both versions are perfectly correct, and I'd say that sometimes, the `if/else` version is clearer. Personally, I do `if/else` if the two bodies are roughly the same size, and only the `if` if its body is short and the would-be `else` body is long, thus saving an indentation level for it. Bonus: if you have a long `if` body and a short `else` body and the `else` ends in `return` (or there's nothing more in the function after the `if/else`), negate the condition and end up with a short `if` body and no `else`.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. Yes I have it as two separate indentations for readability. I could just as well combine everything into a single line and `return 'List' if isinstance(inp, list) else 'Not List'`. I don't agree with pylint here, but anyways I guess that's an opinion and thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: I agree, the `else` version is preferable IMO. Pylint has a lot of dumb ideas, this isn't the only one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga out of curiosity, what are some of the other odd ones, and I'll add those to my pylintrc?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 one that is clearly stupid is: "W1638 ange built-in referenced when not iterating Used when the range built-in is referenced in a non-iterating context (returns an iterator in Python 3)" It's dead wrong about `range` returning an iterator. a `range` object is a perfectly acceptable container.

Comment: https://pycodequ.al/docs/pylint-messages/w1638-range-builtin-not-iterating.html

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset a python 3 range object is not an iterator- you can call list on it multiple times, you can use efficient `in` contains operations etc.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset you are wrong. `range` objects **are not generators**, they aren't even iterators, try `next(range(10))`. You can iterate over a range object as many times as you want, since it isn't an iterator. these are all basic facts about `range` objects that you can easily verify for yourself. `range` objects are essentially [immutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), that support all sequence operations, indexing, slicing (constant time!) etc. They also have constant time membership testing for `int` objects

Comment: Here's a basic implementation of a similar idea to Python's built-in `range`: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/f4372d098913a1f66764833376f0e020 to get a good idea of what it actually is

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Indeed - today I learned! Apologies, and thanks for correcting me. Deleted my comment (which, for posterity, incorrectly claimed that a `range` is a generator and can only be used once).