# Simple return function, what is more Pythonic?

Tags: python

Simple question that I can't find the answer for.

**Take the function:**

The below *looks* nice, i.e. more readable, given the else and the aligned spacing between the two return statement. However the else is completely pointless, and that makes it feel a little dirty.

```
def get_val(self):
    if long_var < other_long_var and var < other_var:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Note the two conditions and the long line, this is to express that the following is not applicable in this example:

```
return true if this else false
```

However the below is not as readable, but only slightly. It is more elegant as the useless else is omitted.

```
def get_val(self):
    if x:
        return true
    return false
```

**Is there a Pythonic bias for either of these styles?**

If not, is it purely down to the developer?

*EDIT: To be clear, it is an example function. I was trying to express the need for a function that has a condition and returns true of false.
This is a purely stylistic question*

Comment: why not use `return x`?

Comment: @ktzr I hope you mean `return bool(x)`.

Comment: why do you think this is _not as readable_. Also this is already discussed @ [It is more efficient to use if-return-return or if-else-return?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191388)

Comment: You can also `return True if x else False`

Comment: Why does it matter if it's pythonic or not? Efficient and readable (for others) code should be the goal.

Comment: @miradulo If you know `x` is bool, `return x` makes more sense. Or if you know your caller only cares about val's truthiness, not the actual val. Of course in a toy example like this with meaningless names that doesn't do anything but raise a `NameError`, it's hard to guess what the actual use looks like…

Comment: @abarnert Who knows, yeah, just pointing out it doesn't stick to their signature.

Comment: Honestly, the fact that this looks like an unnecessary getter method is a lot more of an issue for whether it's Pythonic or not, and the fact that it appears to be getting a global rather than a member even more so.

Comment: Anyway, there are differences in readability and connotations between the two implementations, but they'll only really show up up in more realistic examples. For example, if `x` is an uncommon condition that needs to be dealt with early (like `if not self.initialized: return None`) while the rest of the function is 8 lines of fancy computation, using an `else` is just indenting your main code path. If the two cases are conceptually similar and their implementations are similar, using an else is a way to make that visible. If you're just reproducing `bool(x)`, neither one is worth doing.

Comment: It could be argued that you should only have one `return`.  In a trivial example like this then that would add nothing, but in a larger function there is a case for only having one `return` point at the end of the function.    Like many things in programming, there is no hard rule for when this is better, only when it is easier to maintain

Comment: @cdarke It _could_ be argued, but it's generally not a very compelling argument in Python, and primarily made by people trying to write C style in Python, or people who like to micro-optimize by manually inlining as much as possible into one giant function.

Comment: @ktzr it is simply an example, see my edit.

Comment: @akshat thanks, seems like this is a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such short cases, I would prefer:

```
def get_val(self):
    return x
```

- it is readable for experienced programmers (who know Python)
- performance faster than anything below, though the difference will be minimal

Secondly, in my view still pythonic (often seen in codewars.com):

```
def get_val(self):
    return True if x else False
```

But I guess, the style guides will recommend:

```
def get_val(self):
    if x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Your second example might not be very pythonic ...

In codewars.com I have also often seen:

```
def get_val(x):
    if x == "": return yz
    elif x == "B": return xyz
    else: return z
```

which might be a kind of switch/case imitation in Python, though
I don't think that style guides will support this ...

Comment: Using a chain of `elif` in place of `switch/case` is definitely Pythonic; it's half of [the official design FAQ answer to why Python doesn't have or need `switch/case`](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python). (The other half is dict of values or functions.) Doing the one-liner thing… PEP 8 strongly discourages it, but for really trivial cases like this, you see it in code even by some core devs. (But if the chain is long enough that saving vertical space matters, a dict is likely to be clearer, and more efficient to boot…)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, abarnert. True, a `dict` will be clearer ;) . And yes, the official recommendations might discourage the one liners. But sometimes, in `codewars.com` I found the short solution very tempting ;) .

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to find if the value of a paramater is either True or False, you can use python's built-in function *bool*.

```
x = ""
bool(x)
>>> False

x = "something"
bool(x)
>>> True
```

Also, you should check the official docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you've given (which is minimal and complete, as it should be), both options are clear and easy to understand.

The easiest (and most pythonic) way would be:

```
def get_val(self):
    return bool(x)
```

Let me comment on a more general case. Quoting from `import this`:

> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

While the second option might appear more elegant, it is also ambiguous: Are you returning `False` because `x` is `False`, or because none of the previous `return` statements have been triggered?

Thinking of a slightly more complex example, I'd suggest to use the final return statement to give you e.g. some default option, a warning, or a ValueError.

```
def myfunc(x, mode):
    if mode == 'square':
        return x**2
    if mode == 'cube':
        return x**3
    return x
```

Comment: You might want to justify why you believe it to be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've included a very simple pythonic option and some thoughts on a more general case.

Comment: @DanielLenz thanks for the answer. The Python quote answers the question elegantly I feel - as you put it. Your last example does explain the logic behind my second answer, 'by default return false, unless this is true', but it does also possess some ambiguity as you have stated.