# Distinction between elif and else?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, control-flow

I have the following function in Python:

```
def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,saml_authentication_attributes,groups):
    result = []
    input_length = len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups])
    if input_length == 0:
        log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
        raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)
    if input_length == 1:
        result = [t.strip() for t in saml_authentication_attributes[groups][0].split(',')]
    elif input_length:
        result = saml_authentication_attributes[groups]
    return result
```

Are there any benefits/drawbacks (aside from the logical control flow) - speed, memory, etc. - for replacing the `elif` there with the `else` clause?

Would this be preferable:

```
    def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,saml_authentication_attributes,groups):

        input_length = len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups])

        if input_length == 0:
            log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
            raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)


        return [t.strip() for t in saml_authentication_attributes[groups][0].split(',')] \
            if len(saml_authentication_attributes[groups]) == 1\
            else saml_authentication_attributes[groups]
```

Comment: Changing the `elif` to an `else` would make your code clearer. The condition in `elif input_length` must be true at that point in the code.

Comment: Based on common sense, I would think that `else` would be faster than `elif` as there are no condition checks.

Comment: Faster doesn't matter here.  The speed of checking if a list is empty or not is microscopic.  Go for the clearest expression of the idea.

Comment: Your second version is definitely not preferable. Putting an `if...then` statement into a 'one-liner' that is so long it has to break across 3 lines, just loses clarity with no or negligible performance benefit.

Comment: And performance is not the concern here....! Make the code readable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to shorten the second version of the function to make it both readable and succinct:

```
def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,groups):

    groups_length = len(groups)

    if groups_length == 0:
        log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
        raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)

    return [t.strip() for t in groups[0].split(',')] \
        if groups_length == 1\
        else groups
```

Answer (score 3):

An `else` would be clearer.  Your `elif` will always run, so there's no point having a condition on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first function is already readable enough, and performance is unlikely to be a concern. For maximum readability in a short function, I would write it like this:

```
def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,saml_authentication_attributes,groups):
    inp = saml_authentication_attributes[groups]
    if inp:    
        if len(inp) == 1:
            return [t.strip() for t in inp[0].split(',')]
        else:
            return inp
    else:
        log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
        raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)
```

It seems to me this makes the flow obvious from a quick glance. The `else`s are both unnecessary (because the function will have `return`ed already if the condition was true) and serve only to make it more explicit. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250521/567595) prefer to omit `else` after `return`.

For longer functions it can become a pain to have all of the main logic nested like that, and it will no longer be clear what condition the trailing `else` at the end referred to, so it's more convenient to handle basic problems with the parameters at the top.

```
def _extract_grp_entitlements(self,saml_authentication_attributes,groups):
    inp = saml_authentication_attributes[groups]

    # get the no input error out of the way
    if not inp:
        log.error(self.empty_entitlements_message)
        raise RuntimeError(self.empty_entitlements_message)

    # now do everything else (no need for else)
    if len(inp) == 1:
    # etc.
```