# Python can the line "return x if y" be used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, syntax-error

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9191474/11975758) it is stated that you can use `return A+1 if A > B else A-1`in python 3, yet when i try to use it:

```
def max3(a,b,c):
    return a if a > b and c
    return b if b > c else c
```

i get an invalid syntax error. I've tried looking online but I can't find anything on this, if anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

thanks.

Comment: You're missing the else part

Comment: Functions can have only one return

Comment: @rdas functions can have many return statements without code blocks but only the first one can take effect

Comment: @YangHG *unconditional return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
def max3(a,b,c):
    return a if a > b and a > c else b if b > c else c
```

Just make sure to always have an `else` part, otherwise the expression won't know what to evaluate to. Whether this is the most readable solution is at best questionable. There is no price for fewest lines/bytes (unless you are playing code golf).

Also note that `a > b and c` is **not** the same as `a > b and a > c`. You can shorten that to `b < a > c`, but then readability will take *another* hit.

Comment: Of course this quickly becomes unintelligible, so… please don't and use some other approach.

Comment: I agree, the question is, however, purely academical to begin with. And this demonstrates  the workings of the `a if b else c` syntax.

Comment: If we discuss academically, please do not call this syntax an "operator".

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Even the official python docs refer to the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) as the "ternary operator".

Comment: Still, it's not an operator.

Answer (score 1):

The second return statement in the function will not have any effect and the function will return whatever is returned by the first return statement.
In the first return statement there must be an else otherwise it will be an syntax error.
So, it should be

```
return a if a>b else b
```

To evaluate max in 3 ints

```
return a if a > b and a > c else b if b > c else c
```

Answer (score -1):

def max3(a,b,c):
    if a > b and a > c:
         return a
    elif b > c else a > c:
         return b

## use colons at the end of a conditional statement.

## using an "else:" part is not compulsory.

Comment: the line " elif b > c and a > c: return b" must be on other line.

Comment: in my answer all the lines got into one line.

Comment: write return statement after the conditional statement. Please upvote my answer.