# Point of exit from a method in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In Eclipse, is there any way to find which return statement a method returned from without logging flags at every return statment?

For example:

```
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof ABC)) {
        return false;
    }
    ABC other = (ABC) obj;
    if (var1 == null) {
        if (other.var1 != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!var1.equals(other.var1)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this case, how do I find out at which point my equals method returned?

Comment: Use the debugger and set a breakpoint on each return statement.

Comment: Maybe this is why a good practice is to make one single return per function...

Comment: @Marvo This will work. I can go into debug mode and execute line-by-line. I wouldn't want to put breakpoints on the 150 returns that this equals function has. Thanks.

Comment: @AlastorMoody You can also put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method, and then step through the method line by line.

Comment: @CoryKendall That's what I did and successfully figured out the problem. Thanks everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but a more understandable and debug friendly code can be with a boolean local variable that represents the result.

then you can see with debugger who assign it when and the return value before returned.

Comment: So does the debugger pause while accessing a variable if I have put a breakpoint at the variable declaration? I will have to try that out.

Comment: It would not pause at each access, but you would have to assign the variable to false instead of the return and handle the boolean at the end. You can assign breakpoints at each place where you assign the variable to false

Answer (score 3):

No.  This is one reason that some people prefer single point of exit:
[Why should a function have only one exit-point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838828/why-should-a-function-have-only-one-exit-point)

Note also the links in the first comment on that question.

Answer (score 2):

Use breakpoints in debug mode.