# C# error - "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#

This is fairly simple method. I use `entity framework` to get some data and then check some values in a `if statement`. However right now the method is marked with red.

This is my method:

```
private bool IsSoleInProduction(long? shoeLastID)
{
    if (shoeLastID == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Resources.ERROR_SAVE, 
                        "Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }

    ISoleService soleService = 
        UnityDependencyResolver.Instance.GetService<ISoleService>();

    List<Sole> entity = 
        soleService.All().Where(s => s.ShoeLastID == shoeLastID).ToList();

    if (entity.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach (var items in entity)
        {
            if (items.Status == 20)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you modify the code after the answers? The above code should work.

Comment: wouldn't the if else status check only ever check the first element of the list? I'd think you just need the one return false afterwards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to take advantage of LINQ with [An](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)y, replace your code:

```
if (entity.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (var items in entity)
    {
        if (items.Status == 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

with simpler code:

```
 return entity.Any(item => item.Status == 20);
```

Or even better performance:

```
 return soleService.All()
              .Any(s => s.ShoeLastID == shoeLastID
                     && s.Status == 20);
```

**Edit:** With you comment, below code is what you need:

```
  List<Sole> entity =  soleService.All()
                            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.ShoeLastID == shoeLastID);

  return entity == null ? false : entity.Status == 20;
```

Comment: The version using linq is not equivalent to the original, which may return false if there are items with Status != 20 at the beginning of the list.

Comment: @josef.axa: No, it returns if one item which has Status == 20, if not, will search until found. You need to run this code to see

Comment: @josef.axa That is a good abservation. The equivalent version would be something like: return (soleService.All().First(s => s.ShoeLastID == shoeLastID).Status == 20)

Comment: @josef.axa: I have included the link on this answer

Comment: What I meant is the linq version will return true if the list contains any element with status == 20, while the original will only return true if the first item has status == 20.

Comment: I suspect the linq version is what the author wanted though, I just wanted to point out that there was a difference.

Answer (score 3):

If there's no item in your `entity` collection, then neither of the containing if/else branches will be executed. In this case there's no return statement anymore, because the `else` part won't be executed, and outside your `foreach` you have no return statement.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not "see" that if

```
entity.Count() != 0
```

then your loop

```
foreach (var items in entity)
```

will run at least once. Therefore it sees a possibility of running the `forech` zero times, and not running the `else` block.

Suppose first time the `entity` is *enumerated*, it yields some (finite number of) items. Then the `Count` will be non-zero. Then suppose next time the same `entity` is enumerated *then* it yields no items! That would cause your code to "fall through" without returning.

It is very probably that you can guarantee that the source yields the same number of items each time it is re-enumerated. But the compiler cannot.

Solution: Just skip `if (entity.Count() != 0)` and do `foreach` right away.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't retrun anything from this code block

```
if (entity.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var items in entity)
                {
                    if (items.Status == 20)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // return someting
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

What will be your `entity.Count()` is not `0` and your `entity` doesn't have any `items`?

That means your `if` block will work but `foreach` part will not work. Since your `if` part doesn't have any return statement, that's why you get an error.

You should put return statement in your `if` part.

```
if (entity.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (var items in entity)
    {
        if (items.Status == 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //return true or false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider doing the following. This will adhere to the "**[single exit-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838828/why-should-a-function-have-only-one-exit-point)**" principle (which can sometimes help improve code clarity), and ensure you have a default value in any case:

```
private bool IsSoleInProduction(long? shoeLastID)
{
    // The main change: A default value, assuming "no":
    var isSoleInProduction = false; 

    if (shoeLastID == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Resources.ERROR_SAVE, 
                        "Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        isSoleInProduction = false;
    }

    ISoleService soleService = 
        UnityDependencyResolver.Instance.GetService<ISoleService>();

    List<Sole> entity = 
        soleService.All().Where(s => s.ShoeLastID == shoeLastID).ToList();

    if (entity.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach (var items in entity)
        {
            if (items.Status == 20)
            {
                isSoleInProduction = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSoleInProduction = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isSoleInProduction = false;
    }    

    return isSoleInProduction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your entity collection has no elements you will not reach a return statement - you need to add a return false forexample as last statement

Answer (score 0):

As the error states there can be cases in which none of your return clause is evaluated (e.g. if there are no elements in your list).
To quickly solve it you can put a default return statement, for example by moving the last `return` clause outside the `else` statement. But it really depends on the behavior you'd expect.

```
 private bool IsSoleInProduction(long? shoeLastID)
        {
            if (shoeLastID == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Resources.ERROR_SAVE, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
            ISoleService soleService = UnityDependencyResolver.Instance.GetService<ISoleService>();
            List<Sole> entity = soleService.All().Where(s => s.ShoeLastID == shoeLastID).ToList();

            if (entity.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var items in entity)
                {
                    if (items.Status == 20)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't guarantee that the first call to `Count` means that the `foreach` will loop at least once (with good reason, because you could, if you wished, create a collection where this wasn't true). You can do this instead (with no need for the outer `if`):

```
foreach (var items in entity)
{
    if (items.Status == 20)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return false;
```