# Pros and cons of forbidding an empty string argument and throwing a RuntimeException in order to prevent the method from proceeding

Tags: java, spring, illegalargumentexception, string

Say I have the following method definition in a Spring **service layer**:

```
@Override
public boolean passwordsMatch(String encrypted, String plain) {
      if (encrypted == null || encrypted.isEmpty() || plain == null || plain.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One argument is null or empty");
        }
      return passwordEncoder.matches(plain, encrypted);
   }
```

It is called by a Spring MVC application controller that **wants to check whether the new password provided by a user** (here called "plain") **matches the user's current password** (here called "encrypted").

***Should I really be throwing an IllegalArgumentException (or any subtype of RuntimeException) if the new password provided by the user is empty*** (`plain.isEmpty()`)?

I am 95% sure I am going to remove this check but I'd be curious to hear arguments in favor of keeping the check in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IllegalArgumentException` should be your first choice whenever you get an argument that you don't like within a method (that's the very purpose of this exception). So, unless you already have (or feel the need to implement) a more specific / meaningful exception, I think it's OK to stick with IllegalArgument/IllegalState for the sake of consistency.

However, it may be a good idea to point out the specific argument that you don't like in the exception message. And by the way, Guava provides very nice support for such validations with its [`Preconditions`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) utility.

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(encrypted != null && !encrypted.isEmpty(), "The old password hash is empty");
Preconditions.checkArgument(plain != null && !plain.isEmpty(), "The new password is empty");
```

---

Now that you've clarified the actual question scope, I would say that you're the only one to decide whether your method should proceed if provided with null or empty arguments, after figuring out what exactly this method is supposed to check.

Based on the name of your method, I would say that it should at most disallow `null` values, as empty passwords can still be matched against their encrypted representation. The "minimum password length" rule should most likely be implemented elsewhere; this method should only report whether a plain password matches a hash, disregarding whether it's a legal password or not.

Comment: Also, Java 7 has `Objects.requireNonNull(arg, String)` for `null` checks.

Comment: I have not chosen a completely appropriate title for my post: I meant "pros and cons of **disallowing** and throwing any runtime exception if a empty string argument is provided". Editing my title now.

Comment: @balteo: So you started a whole `IllegalArgumentException` war just for fun ??  Just kidding :)

Comment: @balteo Always try to throw the most acceptably specific `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote too fast. The method seems to be some kind of service method for comparing passwords. The domain is irrelevant. In this specific case it makes sense to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the provided arguments are `null` for example, but not for empty Strings as that might actually be a password.

---

In a use case that involves domain validation, I wouldn't go with `IllegalArgumentException`. Your `User` instance (or whatever) would not be in a valid state if its password was empty. You should therefore throw some kind of `InvalidDomainException`, ex. `InvalidPasswordException` (or use a `BindingResult` with a `Validator`).

Comment: Given your explanation, it's difficult to figure out what would be a proper use-case for throwing an IAE. Do you think it's simply bad practice to use it ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu In a service layer method, IMO it makes sense to throw an IAE. If you additionally write it into the API (ex. javadoc), it's even better.

Comment: I was about to say that any validation is a "domain validation" for a properly defined "domain", but you clarified your point of view in the meantime. As a side note, declaring the thrown exceptions -- even runtime ones -- in your method signature could be the best documentation.

Comment: Good point about "as that might actually be a password". Actually empty strings are disallowed as passwords in the app. But this other constraint is checked elsewhere.

Comment: @balteo Good. That's the point I was trying to make. In a Spring application, you would probably use a `Validator` with `BindingResult` and `@Valid` to validate your model.