# i can't understand this function on this hash program.. help me explain?

Tags: c

ok this is one of the functions on the hash program provided by my lecturer.. It has many commands that I've never tried before, like strdup, hash, etc.. from my point of view, this function is used to add the columns to the hash (hash is like tables right??) in the main program there's a repeat of this function using for 5 times because there are 5 table description... so here's the function:

```
int install (char *name, char *desc){
unsigned int hi;
node *np;
if((np=lookup(name))==NULL){
    hi=hash(name);
    np=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (np==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    np ->name = m_strdup(name);

    if (np->name == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    np -> next=hashtab[hi];
    hashtab[hi]=np;
}
else{
    free (np->desc);
}
np -> desc=m_strdup(desc);

if (np->desc == NULL){
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

}

why are there so many returns?? if the function return 0, it means the function isn't successfully doing what it's supposed to right?? if it already returns 0, is it possible for the function to return 1?? well i'm totally noob at this.. Thanks for your kind help :D

Comment: The meaning of an integer return value is independent of its numerical value. Sometimes `0` is used to denote "failure" and sometimes it is used to denote "success."

Comment: In your code, return 0 is an error condition ( there were memory allocation problems ), a return 1 means all went well.

Answer (score 0):

That function as written will return 0 if something went wrong and 1 otherwise. This is a reasonably common but by no means universal idiom.

Regarding the multiple return statements only one of them will be executed for a particular call to the function, since what return does is stop executing the current function and go back (i.e. *return*) to the caller.  Different calls to the same function can take different paths through the code and therefore hit different return statements, but any single call will only hit one return.

The use of multiple return statements in a method is a commonly debated style issue. It can arguably make code both easier and harder to read depending on how it's done.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838828/why-should-a-function-have-only-one-exit-point) & [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement) for some views on that.