# bad try catch block design?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Whenever I use try-catch blocks in my code, my code always follows a pattern.
First a try-catch block to open a resource followed by a null check and finally a try-catch block to read the resources.
Is this a messy pattern? If so, what should the good design look like?

Here is an example of what I mean

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\program.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (process == null) {
        return;
    }
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like return statements mid way through a method.

Comment: @BevynQ that's an entirely different discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838828/why-should-a-function-have-only-one-exit-point

Comment: If you get an exception while creating the process you should return from catch block, why to check for null on 'process' afterward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are suppressing the exceptions in your code, which is why you need the null check. Particularly since this is in a `main()` method you could just let the exceptions propagate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\program.exe");
  try (BufferedReader reader =
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

This will still print a stack trace when there's an issue (since Java prints the stack trace of any exceptions that get thrown from `main()`), but you know that `process` can never be `null`. In general you should avoid over-eagerly catching exceptions - only catch them if there's something *you can do about it*. If not, pass them off to the caller (possibly wrapping them in a new exception type).

If you just don't care about the exceptions and don't expect them in practice you can make them `RuntimeException`s instead. This still lets you avoid needless null-checks but also doesn't require you to annotate your methods with `throws`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\program.exe");
    try (BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
        "Unexpected exception while executing a subprocess", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I thought it was a good habit to catch all the exceptions and log them or something.

Comment: Sure, logging exceptions is a reasonable thing to do *if that's what you want to happen*. It's certainly not what you should do by default. Fail-fast by default, and suppress/log exceptions only if that's what you intend.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this issue!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)