# Java best practice: favor immutability or cleaner execution flow?

Tags: java, algorithm, software-quality

I've been reviewing java pull requests for a while now, and I often encounter code like this:

```
String getBar(Foo foo) {
    String bar = "Unknown"; // default value
    if (foo.getBarHandler() != null) {
        bar = foo.getBarHandler().getBar(); // probable mutation
    }
    return bar; // single return
}
```

Of course this is pseudo code, the point here is that we instantiate a "default" `bar`, maybe we mutate it, and then we return it.

I think mutability here is a bit evil, and I always propose do refactor it this way:

```
String getBar(Foo foo) {
    if (foo.getBarHandler() == null) { // invert the condition to act like a guard clause
        return "Unknown"; // default value is indented
    }
    return foo.getBarHandler().getBar(); // happy path the least indented
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that we have now two `return` and the execution flow of this method might be more confusing.

I am seeking opinions here, what do you think is the best solution, and why ?

Comment: Multiple "return" statements may also be considered as an evil by purists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838828/why-should-a-function-have-only-one-exit-point :)

Comment: Personally I think it much easier to read code with guards and early returns. It lets me get that edge-case out of the way when reading the rest of the function.

Comment: *"mutability"*: A string is immutable. What you have here is reassignment.

Comment: Another option is the conditional operator `? :`

Comment: I'd make `getBarHandler` return `Optional<Bar>` and use `return foo.getBarHandler().map(BarHandler::getBar).orElse("Unknown");`

Comment: [Return Early Pattern](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8)

Comment: `final String bar; if (foo.getBarHandler() != null) { bar = foo.getBarHandler().getBar(); } else { bar = "Unknown"; /* default value */ } return bar;` single return, no variable is reassigned. Or use a conditional expression: `final String bar = foo.getBarHandler() != null ? foo.getBarHandler().getBar() : "Unknown"; /* default value */ return bar;` (the variable can be inlined)

Comment: Either one is fine.  When performing a code review, you shouldn't expect the author to have to same arbitrary biases that you do.

Answer (score 1):

Just my humble opinion here:
both methods are O(1) and in terms of performance doesn't change anything.

it's just a matter of "clean code" apparently. Personally I prefer the second version even if multi-return is often discouraged. But here we are talking about a 3 line code, should not be an issue here.

this method could be even 1 line:

```
String getBar(Foo foo) {
    return foo.getBarHandler() == null ? "Unknown" : foo.getBarHandler().getBar();
}
```

I suggest here to don't "look for the evil" but instead focus on the functional aspect